# TFServer : Cannot update data because the server clock may have been set incorrectly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am working on project which is on the TFServer. every thing was fine till today which the server time changed to 4 hours ahead. i cann't check in any thing from then because i get the following error

TFS2010 TF54000: Cannot update data because the server clock may have been set incorrectly. Contact your Team Foundation Server Administrator

i searched in internet i found this
http://www.windows-tech.info/4/d1a37cfc6cf38a79.php

so i look into the tbl_Changeset i have two records for today

780 1   2013-12-09 11:13:56.930     807 1
781 1   2013-12-09 11:16:40.727     808 1

i am writing this post on 14:00 which definately bigger than 11:13, so i couldn't checkin again?

Comment: "Contact your Team Foundation Server Administrator "

Answer (score 9):

This usually occurs when changesets have future times, possibly due to a system clock being temporarily set in the future. To fix it, first run this query against the relevant collection DB (e.g. Tfs_DefaultCollection):

```
SELECT TOP 20 *
FROM tbl_ChangeSet
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

You will probably see a row with a CreationDate in the future

Update the errored rows to a sensible time in the past:

```
UPDATE tbl_ChangeSet SET CreationDate = '2014-07-10 05:51:04.160' WHERE ChangeSetId = 73
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. In our case the TFS runs a german locale so we had to change the date accordingly, i.e. "10-07-2014 05:51:04.160"

Answer (score 3):

That happens when the TFS server clock has been tampered. A common scenario is the server clock changed backwards after a check-in has been submitted. The times you see on tbl_Changeset are in UTC. You can try modifying the records several hours backwards, i.e.: from 2013-12-09 11:13:56.930 to 2013-12-09 00:13:56.930

Answer (score 0):

About **TFS Clock Error**: It happens when your server machine time changed and you at time of Checkin & Checkout it put dates according to server in SQL Server Database hosting TFS Porject Collection. It update multiple tables not only tbl_ChangeSet or tbl_PendingChangeSet. I got it working by updating dates in multiple tables. What I did is mentioned below:

///Generated Script at once for all table for field data_type='datetime' Please see image below.
[image]

After above part: I copied Resutl Script to new query window and make it Common Table expression to limit the list accordingly. See Image Below.

[image]

See the result below: You will have list of tables with field name you need to update if date is mismatch. Changing of date you can do it with TSQL Query or can manually change directly editing in table. 
***Note: Please take your database Backup first. :) Enjoy!!!***

[image]